# RegExp.test() returns different result for same str depending on how (where ?) it is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've just notice a strange JS behavior that lead to an annoying bug..

Basically, I test a str with a RegExp object (.test() method) in a if statement.
For the same string tested, if in my code I have only a if, the regexp.test() return true and it goes fine into the if.

The problem is if I had a else (and I need it), for some reason, for the same str tested, the regexp.test() returns false and it goes to the else...

What is this behavior ?

I have run many tests...

TL/DR : For the same string tested on the same RegExp, if there is only a IF statement the regexp.test() returns true, but if I had a else it returns false.

```
some code
```

I forgot to say that the bug doesn't occurs with all words..

http://jsfiddle.net/zrwkU/13/

Write the word "armoire" in the text field and press enter.
This jsfiddle has the "else return false" and nothing happens.

Remove the "else return false" in the searchDeeper function ( if (regexp.test(tested)){ ) and do the test again. Now it goes into the if and a msgbox popup.

Comment: What you're describing is impossible. Post your code.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code? You seem to be able to reduce your problem to a few lines, show us those lines.

Comment: @Pointy well not if the regex has `g` flag, then `.test` behaves like this, doesn't it?

Comment: @Esailija ah, good point; still it depends on the actual code involved. And while that point about the "g" flag is true, a single call to `.test()` in the `if`  will do what it does regardless of whether there's an `else`. **We need to see the code.**

Comment: I will show the code, but it's long..

Comment: @MarcDupuis - we dont need your whole codebase. Just a small, self-contained sample that demonstrates the problem!

Comment: @Pointy ok seems there is no g flag, so it's just a logic error

Comment: The problem is only on some words..

Comment: -1. That code is not runnable, not self-contained and is therefore near-on useless. (Plus its the `.exec` that is the problem not the `.test` as specified in the question)

Comment: I'm making a jsfiddle. No it's the .test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only issue is that where you have

```
}else{
    return false;
}
```

What you actually want is

```
}else{
   continue;
}
```

in order to continue the outer loop `for (var k in cats){`.

As per this update: http://jsfiddle.net/zrwkU/14/

By way of explanation - with your code, as soon as a call to `test` fails, thats it - out of the method you jump using `return false`. By changing to a `continue` you continue to "search deeper" in other categories too.

Comment: @MarcDupuis - don't we all do it. But rule #1 when using a widely used tech such as Javascript - the bug is in your code. Rule #2 - the bug is in your code.

Comment: To be honest I didn't even knew the 'continue' command. I've learned a lot today, thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 47):

### /regex/g.lastIndex = 0

With patterns having the global `'g'` flag set, the `RegExp` methods; `test()` and `exec()` keep track of the last place they matched and store this integer number in the RegExp object's: `lastIndex` property. This index is automatically advanced as each match is applied to *any* string. Note that both `test()` and `exec()` behave this way. Once any match fails, this last index property is automatically reset to zero. You can manually reset it to zero yourself, too, and it sure looks like that's what you need to do here. Add a line to reset `RegExp.lastIndex` like so:

```js
if (regexp != null){
    regexp.lastIndex = 0;
    if (regexp.test(tested)){
        alert('ok');
        regexp.lastIndex = 0;
        var res = regexp.exec(tested);
        tested = tested.replace(res, '<span class="underlined">' + res + '</span>');
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is another solution which avoids this *last-index-issue* altogether. It uses the `String.match()` method instead:

### A `String.match()` alternative:

```js
if (regexp != null){
    if (tested.match(regexp)){
        alert('ok');
        regexp.lastIndex = 0;
        var res = tested.match(regexp);
        tested = tested.replace(res, '<span class="underlined">' + res + '</span>');
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct, but the OP's code (at least the one he showed us) does not use the global flag. Esailija has already deleted his answer...

Comment: I was getting true then false then true in something I was doing. Had left the `g` modifier on from testing my string in regex101 - removing the `g` modifier solved my issue.

Comment: Great catch, you can also create new RegExp instance every time to avoid this manual reset...

Comment: 10x a lot, cause I spent a lot of time for searching root of almost the same problem. God bless you))

Comment: Thank you, sir. You saved my life. I was beating my head against the wall for quite a few hours because of this annoying problem. Thank you!